# How to open file maker .fp3 files without file maker installed?

Tags: database, filemaker

A client of mine sent me his db to review before starting a new project with him, as he said, he is using file maker pro 4.
He sent me a list of .fp3 files, but I can't find file maker 4 or 5 somewhere for free to download and check these files, and he can't find a setup file for file maker for me.

Is there a a way to open these files and see the db structure?

Comment: Have you tried the current version (there's a free trial)? It must be able to convert the old files.

Comment: Yes, and I got that i must have at least Version 5 to be able to convert to newer version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to ask someone with FileMaker 5 or 6 to convert the files into v5 and then convert them further to the current version (v12). E.g. I can do that; my email is mikhail -dot- edoshin -you-know-what- gmail -dot -com.